# How do you draw a line on a tiff file? (complete beginner)

Tags: shapefile, geotiff-tiff, line, mapping

I am a complete beginner to QGIS and everything that surrounds it so bare with me. I have a tiff file (map) that I have managed to georeference. Now I want to draw a simple line (trail) on the tiff file and still have it georeferenced and in tiff format. What is the easiest way to do so?

What I have tried is plotting a line on a new shapefile layer. The problem with that is I can't get the line (shapefile) to merge with my map (tiff file). I have looked into Rasterize but got overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

First create a vector layer with the line you want to "draw" on the raster, then use this tool [Rasterize (overwrite with fixed value)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-overwrite-with-fixed-value), remember this tool will override the values of your raster, so make a copy to ensure that you will not spoil your georeferenced raster.

You must set the `Input vector layer` to your vector where you have drown the line.

Then in the `Input raster layer` set the raster (your georeferenced image).

And finally set the `A fixed value to burn` parameter to the value that will override the values of the raster that are under the line.

Remember that there's no output because the raster is modified.